# Autoinstall xubuntu using packer and vsphere

Tags: xubuntu, autoinstall

I've been trying to create xubuntu template on vmware using packer and vsphere.

I run into problem, because whatever I do in boot command i get into xubuntu live session-"xubuntu try mode"

and nothing else happens.

```
  boot_command= [
...
    "linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=\"nocloud;seedfrom=/cida/\"  ---<enter><wait>",
    "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
    "boot<enter>",
    "<enter><f10><wait>"
    ]

  cd_files = ["./http/meta-data", "./http/user-data"]
  cd_label = "cidata"
```

It seems like it does not init cloud-init and user-data file content.

I tried with

```
"linux /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=\"nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://packer_http_server_address:port\"  ---<enter>
```

and I faced the same result- live session.

Have no idea what else can I do to make it works...

I have done the same with ubuntu.iso and it works like a charm.

Comment: Have you looked into these tools may not work with xUbuntu only with Ubuntu?